# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history' when creating model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to build a model with the following architecture:
[image]

The code is as follows:

```
input = Input(shape=(122880))
word_embedding_size = 1024

# Embedding Layer
model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=word_embedding_size, input_length=122880)(input)

# BI-LSTM Layer
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=256, 
                           return_sequences=True, 
                           recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model) 

# TimeDistributed Layer
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="relu"))(model)  

# CRF Layer
crf = CRF(n_tags)
out = crf(model)  # output

model = Model(input, out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=crf_layer.loss_function, metrics=[crf_layer.accuracy])
model.fit(x_train , y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Whenever I am trying to fit the model, I am getting the following error:

```
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-cd4639a42d53> in <module>()
     25 model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=crf_layer.loss_function, metrics=[crf_layer.accuracy])
     26 model.summary()
---> 27 model.fit(x_train , y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

AttributeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:830 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:813 run_step  *
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:771 train_step  *
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:201 __call__  *
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:142 __call__  *
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py:246 call  *
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_contrib/losses/crf_losses.py:54 crf_loss  *
        crf, idx = y_pred._keras_history[:2]
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:401 __getattr__
        self.__getattribute__(name)
    AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'
```

All of my imports are as follows:

```
#Data analysis   |
import sys
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import csv
import nltk
import tensorflow as tf
#Data visualisation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.set(font_scale=1)
#for building the model
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Dense, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, TimeDistributed, Lambda, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras_contrib.layers import CRF
```

I know there are a bunch of questions on this problem and I have read some of those but none of them worked for me. Please help me to solve the error. Thank you

Comment: Please add all imports to your question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i've updated my question, please check

Comment: Make sure all your imports are from the `tensorflow` module.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I've changed it and the error is still the same

Comment: Can you share the updated code ( imports )?

Comment: `from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Dense, Embedding, LSTM, Bidirectional, TimeDistributed, Lambda, Flatten`            
`from tensorflow.keras.models import Model`         
`from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam`        
`from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential`        
`from keras_contrib.layers import CRF`

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal can you help me?

Comment: @Sarada , can you using the `CRF` layer from TensorFlow Addons? See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/CRF).

Comment: @Sarada, `Keras-contrib` is deprecated. Use TensorFlow Addons(`tfa`) instead as suggested above. In your case use `tfa.layers.CRF` and let us know? Thanks!